# Global variable php

Tags: global-variables

I have two php blocks inside index.php as given below.

```
<?php
 $a="hello";
 $b="world";
?>
<?php 
 echo $a . $b;
?>
```

Here in the second php block, I want to echo the values of variable a and b which are declared in first php block. What shall I do to get those variables in my second php block?

Comment: Which means there is no way to share variables between php blocks ?

Comment: Couldn't you actually try this yourself faster than you could ask it?

Comment: @Uvais - try it and see, don't keep asking questions that you could answer for yourself quicker than you can ask them

Comment: Sorry guys.I am very new to PHP. I was not getting the values. Might be becouse of some other errors. Let me check. I was confused.Thats why ask.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @alexxus there is the ever so slight chance that the computer will simply blow up if you use php wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. Variables are accessible from the 2nd block already. PHP doesn't care where you open or close PHP-mode in a document.

Comment: Thanks for your quicker reply. Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. All variables in php are valid for whole script. Only difference are variables inside functions or classes. They are limited to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

you can still access variables from second code block, code block doesn't make any difference in variable scope.

your output will be: helloworld

Answer (score 0):

You have to do nothing in particular.

Variables created in the first block are and remain accessible in the second one as in all your script.

When PHP parses a file, it looks for the opening and closing tags that define the code that must be interpreted. It allows PHP to be embed in all kinds of documents as all that is outside the tags is ignored.

Btw, You have an error in your title. It should be Global vari**ab**le ;)